# String Manipulation: Change characters in directory path to look like directory path on linux shell

Tags: c++, linux, windows, directory, c-strings

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and I use Windows 7. I want to know how to get the current directory the C++ file is opened in (when compiled into an exe file) and make the directory path look like a Linux shell directory path (e.g. change `\` to `/`). I am currently using this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
//Variables
    TCHAR name[UNLEN + 1];
    CHAR hostname[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;


    TCHAR hname[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD hsize = UNLEN + 1;

    //Username
    if (GetUserName((TCHAR*)name, &size))
    {
        wcout << L"[" << name << L"@";
        //PC Name
        if (GetComputerName((TCHAR*)hname, &hsize))
        {
            wcout << hname << L" ]# ";
        }
    }
    else
        //Not required
        cout << "Hello, unnamed person!\n";





}
```

Comment: [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) ought to be useful in this case.

Comment: Thanks but how would you display it to look like how it looks when displayed on Linux shell?

Comment: There are many things going on there. `<filesystem>` helps with a lot. It abstracts the OS directory separators away etc. Take one problem at a time, but use `<filesystem>` while doing so to get the best support. Read about what it can do.

Comment: What are you going to do about drive letters?

Comment: I will not display the drive letters.